# preview math formula in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, auctex

I would to include and preview some math formula inside an `org-mode` buffer, but can't find any way. 
I've read about `auctex` but how can I enable it in a non `tex-mode` ? 
Don't know really from where to start...
thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you seen this http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-latex-preview.html ?

Comment: You are right, I read this tutorial and forgot about it. I tried org-preview-latex-fragment but it has no effect, even though dvipng is installed.

Comment: I have not tried what you want, but... inserting and running some (foreign language) code into a org-mode buffer seems like a job for [org-babel](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/intro.html). Have you looked at it?

Comment: @Omar's suggestion (`org-latex-preview`) works for me (Emacs 25, Org-mode 8.3.6). Have you tried it without loading your Emacs config file (`emacs -Q`)?